# Filtering javascript object using .filter()

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Does someone have an idea about this kind of filtering javascript object using .filter() function:

let say I have:

```
docs: [
{
  "name": "Mike",
  "address": "Canada",
  "gender": "Male"
},
{
  "name": "Jean",
  "address": "China",
  "gender": "Female"
},
{
  "name": "Sakura",
  "address": "England",
  "gender": "Female"
}
]
```

Is it possible to filter like this:

```
name = ''
age = ''
gender = 'Female'
```

because doing it like this:

```
filtered_docs = docs.filter(function (el) {
   return el.name == '' ||
      el.address == '' ||
      el.gender == 'Female';
});
```

will return all.

and doing like this:

```
filtered_docs = docs.filter(function (el) {
   return el.name == '' &&
      el.address == '' &&
      el.gender == 'Female';
});
```

will return nothing.

**UPDATE:** 
I just want to return data based on that conditions. 
I expect to return 2 record with female gender

**UPDATE**
This is what i'm trying to achieve
[image]

Comment: `I just want to return data that gender is female and the rest is empty string` then returning nothing is the correct result is it not? Since there is no data with empty string as name or address the filter should return no data

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to count the number of females?  Just filter on gender and then check the length.

Comment: let me edit my post

Comment: `filtered_docs = docs.filter(function (el) {
   return el.name == '' &&
      el.address == '' &&
      el.gender == 'Female';
});
` should work, can you explain what is your expected result?

Comment: yes i updated my post. sorry

Comment: In your example, no name and no address is empty, therefore it is correct to return an empty list. If you want to return all females, just `return el.gender == 'Female';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an objetc for the key/value pairs for filtering and take in a first step only the keys which have a wanted value, like a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value for later filtering.

Then filter the array by checking only the keys with a value to check and take these keys of the filter for checking. Return only the object which match all of the keys and the wanted value.

```js
var docs= [{ name: "Mike", address: "Canada", gender: "Male" }, { name: "Jean", address: "China", gender: "Female" }, { name: "Sakura", address: "England", gender: "Female" }],
    filter = { name: "", age: "", gender: "Female" },
    keys = Object.keys(filter).filter(k => filter[k]),
    result = docs.filter(o => keys.every(k => o[k] === filter[k]));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi Miss Nina, I can't thank you enough. You saved me. It works now. That solution seems so advanced for me now, but I will study it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to filter(i.e. search the array and find the matching object) or do you want to create a new array with gender as female and the rest as empty string ?

If you want to filter, your second method will work. It returns nothing as none of the objects in the docs array match the conditions.

If you want to create a new array, then consider using .map(). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

your condition is wrong, you filter it with gender condition only no need to other fields

```
    filtered_docs = docs.filter(function (el) {return el.gender == 'Female';});
```

Comment: It must be 3 conditions together. Because the filter is from front-end. In the front-end there are three selections of filter, so the user may filter two only and rest is not filtered

Comment: you should trigger the change in selections to filter data with with event "change" 
with && operator all the conditions should be true so if you put "address" as empty string in filtering it will be false because no address property in any object will match the condition empty string.